# Entity Framework Core- Use Expression Tree With Interface As Parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, expression-trees

I will really appreciate some help with following scenario.
I have the following classes:

```
public class Product : IHasPrice
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }

}

public interface IHasPrice
{
    int Price { get; set; }
}

public class ProductProvider
{
    public ProductProvider()
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetByCustomer(string customerId, Expression<Func<IHasPrice, bool>> predicate = null)
    {
        using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var queryable = db.Products.Where(p => p.CustomerId == customerId);
            if (predicate != null)
            {
                return queryable.Where(predicate).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return queryable.ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to enable to use the `ProductProvider` in a way where you can only select by customer, but you can also filter on the price in any way you like (and only on the price). 
This example doesn't work since `queryable.Where` expects parameter with typeof `Expression(Func(Product, bool))`. Is there a way to do it or I must fetch the data to memory before the filtering of the price?

Comment: If you call `GetByCustomer` without predicate value then it should fetch all the data without filtering.

Comment: @TanvirArjel - It will return all the customer products without filtering.

Comment: Are your trying to make filtering with customerId optional as well isn' tit?

Comment: @TanvirArjel - The query for the customer id is mandatory. Within the customer products I want to enable to query by price

Comment: Oh! You are trying add another filter by price, is it?

Comment: Okay! Understood your requiremnt but it seems you have designed the UnitOfWork and repository in wrong way.

Comment: Add your UnitOfWork Code.

Comment: @TanvirArjel - First of all thank you for all your help :-) . This is just an example and it is not the real code. I am not allowed to share the code so I needed to create a demo. I will be happy to fix it if you will tell me where I went wrong

Comment: @TanvirArjel - I removed the UnitOfWork . I feel it doesn't matter for this issue. I used the DataContext directly instead. I will read what you wrote regardless

Comment: Now you would like to filter product by any field okay?

Comment: @TanvirArjel - The requirements remain the same. The customer filter is a must and in addition I want to enable to add a query only for the price (within the customer products)

Comment: I am making it generic. You will price when you will called method. Okay?

Comment: @TanvirArjel - I am sorry but I didn't understand what you mean

Comment: You just use price filter when you will call the provider methods.

Comment: @TanvirArjel Exactly

Comment: Follow the **Ivan Stoev** answer. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `IQueryable<out T>` interface is *covariant*, the passed lambda expression can be used directly with `Where` method:

```
var query = queryable.Where(predicate);
```

The only problem is that now the type of the result query is `IQueryable<IHasPrice>`. You can turn it back to `IQueryable<Product>` using `Queryable.Cast` method:

```
var query = db.Products.Where(p => p.CustomerId == customerId);
if (predicate != null)
    query = query.Where(predicate).Cast<Product>(); // <--
return query.ToList();
```

Tested and working with the latest EF Core 2.2 (might fail in some earlier versions).

---

An alternative solution is to convert the `Expression<Func<IHasPrice, bool>>` to the expected `Expression<Func<Product, bool>>` by "invoking" it:

```
var query = db.Products.Where(p => p.CustomerId == customerId);
if (predicate != null)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Product), "p");
    var body = Expression.Invoke(predicate, parameter);
    var newPredicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Product, bool>>(body, parameter);
    query = query.Where(newPredicate);
}
return query.ToList();
```

Comment: Tried this code, everything compiles great but at run time an error is thrown:
No coercion operator is defined between types 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AnonymousObject' and 'DAL.Models.Product'.

Comment: @TalHumy As I pointed out, the sample query as is with the EFC version mentioned works (w/o exceptions at runtime). If it doesn't work for you, then either the actual query is different (the error message indicates some sort of `Select`) or EFC version is older. In both cases you have to provide additional information if you want the issue resolved.

Comment: This solution did work after I upgraded to EF Core 2.2 . Thank you very much for your help